# Hibernate criteria many to many

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, criteria

I have two entities with many to many relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item implements Comparable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "item_id")
private Integer itemId;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "items_criteria",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "filter_criterion_id"))
private List<FilterCriterion> filterCriteria;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "filter_criteria")
public class FilterCriterion {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "filter_criterion_id")
private Integer filterCriterionId;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "items_criteria",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "filter_criterion_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"))
private List<Item> items;
}
```

I need to write function in ItemDao class that returns List of Items which have all elements of the collection given as an argument. In the example below I use Restrictions.in so the result contains even those Items which contain for example only one FilterCriterion from List given as argument. I need to have in the result only those Items, which contain all of the elements in argument List.

```
public List<Item> getItems(List<FilterCriterion> currentFilterCriteria) {

    Criteria criteria = ht.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Item.class);
    List<Integer>currentFilterCriteriaId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(FilterCriterion criterion : currentFilterCriteria){
        currentFilterCriteriaId.add(criterion.getFilterCriterionId());
    }
    if(!currentFilterCriteriaId.isEmpty()){
        criteria.createAlias("filterCriteria", "f");
        criteria.add(Restrictions.in("f.filterCriterionId", currentFilterCriteriaId));
    }
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll have to fix your mapping. You don't have a bidirectional ManyToMany association here, but two, unrelated, unidirectional ManyToMany associations. One side must be the inverse side by using the mappedBy attribute:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "filterCriteria")
private List<Item> items;
```

Now to your question, one way of doing this is to use such a query. I'll let you translate it to Criteria if you really want to. I'd use HQL instead, since it's so much easier and maintainable:

```
select i from Item i
where :criteriaIdSetSize = (select count(c.id) from Item i2
                             inner join i2.filterCriteria c
                             where c.id in :criteriaIdSet
                             and i2 = i)
```

You should use a Set to hold your criteria IDs rather than a list though, to make sure it doesn't contain duplicates (which would make the result incorrect).

Comment: Thanks for help, I fixed mapping, but in my question I described more simple situation, than it really is. Function getItems really takes more arguments and contains criteria restrictions not only for FilterCriterion. All other restrictions work well.I have no idea how to write HQL query for all of that. Can you help me to create a restriction?